# Set note from custom function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, custom-function

I'm struggling with following issue: 
I have a spreadsheet responsible for tracking my stock market investments. It calls external service to get a CSV with current prices.

So, there is a function `customFunction()` that calls `UrlFetchApp` and returns current price of an item. I'd like it to add a note to the cell that it has been called from, containing current datetime. Something like this:

```
function customFunction() {
  //get price from csv
  var url = "http://sth.com";
  var csv = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var result = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  var currentValue = parseFloat(result[1][6]);

  //set note
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().setNote("Hey, I'm the note with the datetime");

  //return value so it can be set as cell value
  return currentValue;
}
```

I am calling this function from cell E21 (value `=customFunction()`).
And so everything works as planned, except the line that supposed to set a note. I am sure I get correct cell (tested by returning A1notation as a value). I get the error:

```
error: You do not have permission to call setNote
```

Does anybody know if it's possible to set a note to the cell that calls a custom function from that function? Or maybe you have any idea of workaround, like catching the moment that function reloades with new data and using it as a trigger?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is due to permission limitations:https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_custom_functions#permissions
the function  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell() is not anonymous and can't be used here.
Unfortunately I don't know any efficient workaround

Comment: Actually, the problem is setNote. From the link in the answer "Spreadsheet: Read only (can use most get*() methods, but not set*())."